# How do I keep text from wrapping under an element which floats to its left?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have two block elements. The first is floated to the left. I'd expect the right element to be a block as well and retain its square shape. Instead, text within it is wrapping under the element which is floating to the left.

```css
.comment-date {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-date">07/08 23:08</div>
<div class="comment-body">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.
</div>
```

The lorem ipsum text wraps under the date. I'd expect it to retain a block shape, floating to the right of the date. How can I achieve that?

Here is a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/CS2Hs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to the other solutions here would be to simply add a `margin-left` to `.comment-body`. It would also be helpful to apply a set width to `.comment-date`

```
.comment-date { 
  float: left;     
  font-weight: bold;    
  width: 90px;
}
.comment-body {
  margin-left: 90px;
}
```

This will ensure that the text in `.comment-body` does not appear underneath the date.

Here is a demo:

[**--- jsFiddle DEMO ---**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/CS2Hs/6/)

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but it's unfortunate that I would need to set an exact width to the date field. I was hoping that field's width would just grow to whatever size the date text is. Useful answer, but not the ideal solution :)

Comment: In that case, one of the solutions below that floats both elements or uses `inline-block` is your ideal solution. I figured it best not to repeat answers already provided.

Comment: Unfortunately, all those replies require me to set a width as well. And they require a width on the body element where yours requires it only on the date. So I'm liking this solution best at the moment.

Comment: @Ben174 setting the width on the date container isn't necessary. http://jsfiddle.net/CS2Hs/10/

Comment: @Xander - Yes, but it still requires me /knowing/ the width of the date container in order to choose the left margin width.

Answer (score 0):

The body block is not in the float model. Simply set a `float: left` for `.comment-body` too. Also, you could use some widths. See: http://jsfiddle.net/CS2Hs/3/

Comment: I'd rather not have to use widths. But I don't see a way to do it without them. I want the body element to fill the rest of the page, but if I use a width that will not work. If I use a percent, I have to have an idea how wide the date element will stretch.

Comment: You could consider positioning them relative to a parent container, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/CS2Hs/8/. This way the comment body width remains variable.

Comment: Still requires me to position it 110 pixels to the left. What if the date grows to 200 pixels?

Comment: If you want both to be of variable width, you could resort to table display styles, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/CS2Hs/9/.

Comment: Nice!! Does that feel like a hack to you at all, or is that perfectly acceptable?

Comment: It kind of feels like a hack, but it is perfectly valid CSS and does not touch the semantics of the HTML, so you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to understand your problem. As I understand, you want the `.comment-body` to be on the right and the `.comment-date` to be on the left but on the same line.

If I am right, maybe this will works:

```
.comment-date {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.comment-body {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 85%;
}
```

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CS2Hs/4/) just for you ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to set widths. I do not know the widths of either of these elements. I want the left one to grow to fit the text, and the right one to fill the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle appears to be down at the moment so sorry if this doesn't work/isn't what you wanted but have you tried adding "overflow:hidden" to "comment-body"? This creates a new layout context which stops the text from wrapping underneath. I find this amazingly useful! Hope that helps!