# Indent text and images horizontally by the same amount

Tags: css, html

It's kinda hard to describe what I'm trying to do, so take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GinSan/g8mmdcuw/

As you can see, the text flows around the image, but starts at the very left of the side under the image. I want the text to keep the indentation level, even if it's height excels the height of the image. The Images at the bottom should behave like that as well, so that both the the text and the images would be indented from the left side by the image width plus it's right and left margins. 
Just increasing the bottom margin of the image would probably work, however this would push everything underneath it further to the bottom if the text is too short, it has to work with different text lengths.

I accomplished to keep the text indentation at one level by adding this:

```
p.memberlist_descr {
width:70%;
float:left;
}
```

However, since the text now has a defined width, it wouldn't work on smaller screens. Also, this has no effect on the smaller images below.

Is there a way to accomplish this, if both the text length and the width of the box surrounding are unknown?

Comment: Or also [How do I keep text from wrapping under an element which floats to its left?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979556/how-do-i-keep-text-from-wrapping-under-an-element-which-floats-to-its-left)

Comment: This question has been answered here: [Why does CSS float not change the width of the following div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475822/why-does-css-float-not-change-the-width-of-the-following-div).